# Search through multiple files/dirs for string, then print content of text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a small script that will allow me to search through text files located in a specific directory and folders nested inside that one. I've managed to get it to list all files in that path, but can't seem to get it to search for a specific string in those files and then print the full text file.

Code:

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

path = "<PATH>"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            dfiles = str(file)

sTerm = input("Search: ")

for files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        with open(dfiles) as f:
            if sTerm in f.read():
                print(f.read())
```

First part was from a test I did to list all the files, once that worked I tried using the second part to search through all of them for a matching string and then print the full file if it finds one. There's probably an easier way for me to do this.

Comment: Can't you simply use operating system tools like [`grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) for that?

Comment: Yeah, I could use grep for that, but I want to try making something like this. Still learning Python and figured it could be useful to know how to do stuff like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with Python 3.4+ because of [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('/some/dir')

search_string = 'string'

for o in path.rglob('*.txt'):
    if o.is_file():
        text = o.read_text()
        if search_string in text:
            print(o)
            print(text)
```

The code above will look for all `*.txt` in `path` and its sub-directories, read the content of each file in `text`, search for `search_string` in `text` and, if it matches, print the file name and its contents.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. Try to use `pathlib` whenever possible. It will make your code much more simple and readable.

Comment: Come across a small issue. I have two files with identical text, but it stops searching for results after hitting the first one and will only list that one as a match.

Comment: Doesn't make any sense for me because it is scanning every single `.txt` file it sees down that `path`. Are you sure they both end in `.txt`? The code above will scan only those files. How are those files organized (different sub-directories and names)?

Comment: Another probable cause, are you sure they are pure text files? If you are not sure, we need to change the code to operate on bytes instead.

Comment: Just tested here with a bunch of files and the code above was able to list even identical files that had the search string.

Comment: Just thought about another possibility: maybe it is not a file but a symlink and if that is the case, the code above WILL NOT list nor print its contents because symlinks are not real files. Notice the `if o.is_file():`. If you want to change that behavior, replace that test with `if o.is_file() or o.is_symlink():`.

Comment: Yeah, I was just an idiot and put some code under the initial for loop which made sure not all the files were listed. Thought something was wrong, turns out otherwise. Now I'm just trying to list JUST the filenames and not the entire path

Comment: @AustynHoward, To list just the file name, replace that `print(o)` with `print(o.name)`. :-)

Comment: I figured it was something to do with `name` started reading some of the docs for `pathlib`